# Pig Latin converter using toupper

Tags: c++, string, loops, character

I'm having trouble converting using toupper on the first character in my string.

I used `tolower(first[0])` to turn the first letter into lower case.

Why doesn't `toupper(first[0])` make the first character upper case?

Also, is there a way to move the first character in a string to the last spot?

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

int main ()
{

  char ans;

  do{

    string first, last;
    char first_letter, first_letter2;

    cout << "This program will convert your name " 
     << "into pig latin.\n";
    cout << "Enter your first name: \n";
    cin >> first;
    cout << "Enter your last name: \n";
    cin >> last;

    cout << "Your full name in pig latin is ";

    for(int x = 0; x < first.length(); x++){
      first[x] = tolower(first[x]);
    }

    for(int x = 0; x < last.length(); x++){
      last[x] = tolower(last[x]);
    }

    first_letter = first[0];

    bool identify;

    switch (first_letter)
      {
      case 'a':
      case 'e':
      case 'i':
      case 'o':
      case 'u':
    identify = true;
    break;

      default:
    identify = false;
      }

    if(identify == true){
      toupper(first[0]);

      cout << first << "way" << " ";
    }

    first_letter2 = last[0];

    bool identify2;

    switch (first_letter2)
      {
      case 'a':
      case 'e':
      case 'i':
      case 'o':
      case 'u':
    identify2 = true;
    break;

      default:
    identify2 = false;
      }

    if(identify2 == true){
      toupper(first[0]);

      cout << last << "way" << endl;
    }

    cout << "You you like to try again? (Y/N)\n";
    cin >> ans;

  } while(ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y');

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: I need to make them all lower case first, in case the user inputs all upper case letters. The program's final output should be a name and last name in pig latin with only the first letters capitalized (that's why I need toupper after the switch statements), such as Oscarway Allenway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a simple blunder, compare

```
first[x] = tolower(first[x]);
```

with

```
toupper(first[0]);
```

usual case of the 'can't see the obvious thing missing' syndrome... I hate those mistakes.

As for moving the first character to the end I'd usually just use [`substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) for a simple case:

```
str = str.substr(1) + str[0];
```

Comment: Thank you so much!